# How to determine which day of a year belongs to what month?

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm a beginner and I gotta write a function in SML.

The assignment question is :

> write a function named `what_month` that takes the number of a day (e.g., 257, assuming 365 days a year) as input, and returns the number of the month, that this day belongs to.
>
> Example: `what_month(40)` should return `2` (February).

Comment: Do you know how to do it by hand? Once you have figured out an algorithm, it should be fairly easy translate to ML.

Comment: I've wrote the algorithm in a .txt file but I don't know how do I upload it in the page, can U guide me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the simple case(that doesn't account for leap year), you can define a list of days in months `months_days`, and a recursive helper function `aux`, that takes an `int` called `sum` and an `int list` called `numbers` , and returns an `int` `n` such that the first `n` elements of the list add to less than `sum`, but the first `n + 1` elements of the list add to `sum` or more.

```
val month_days= [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

fun what_month(day :int) =
 let  
   fun aux(sum :int,  numbers: int list) =
    let
      val numbers_tail = tl numbers
    in
      if sum <= (hd numbers)
      then 1
      else    
        1 + aux(sum, (hd numbers + hd numbers_tail)::(tl numbers_tail))
    end
 in
   aux(day, month_days)
 end
```

Comment: I've another question, Tarrsalah, I think you can help me, so just check it, I'm waiting, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this could be to create a list of how many days there are in each month.

Such a list could look like this

```
days_in_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, ...]
```

Then you could easily count down your input number according to how many days each month has. When you reach a number which are smaller than the next months number of days, the input number must belong to the month you had reached.

Beware that this doesn't account for leap year. But that should not bee that difficult to work into it as well, if needed.

Comment: I don't see where you are going with that comment.

Comment: my problem with this function was solved, thank you Jesper, your solution was useful. I've another question just check and help me if it's possible, thanks again