# how to get an int list of months by giving two days of a year?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

write a function named month_range that takes two days of a year named day_one and day_two (e.g. 65, 128, assuming the year has 365 days) as input and return an int list of its months. 
the size of this int list must be `day_two - day_one + 1;`
be aware, if day_one>day_two, size of list = 0

example : `month_range(25,36) should return [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]`January(25,26,27,..,31) and February(1,2,..,5)

I wrote the code but it doesn't work :

```
 fun month_range (day1:int,day2:int) =
 let
   val month_days= [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
 fun what_month(day :int) =
   let  
   fun aux(sum :int,  numbers: int list) =
let
  val numbers_tail = tl numbers
in
  if sum <= (hd numbers)
  then 1
  else    
    1 + aux(sum, (hd numbers + hd numbers_tail)::(tl numbers_tail))
end
in
  aux(day, month_days)
end
in
  if (day1>day2)
  then []
  else what_month(day1) @ what_month(day2)
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a "post your homework assignment, we'll write the code for you" site. Please post the work you've done trying to solve this yourself, explain how it's not working the way you expect, and we'll be glad to try and help you figure out why it's not working. We're not doing your homework for you here. If you need help understanding the question's requirements, ask your professor or teaching assistant. Good luck.

Comment: you have to get your hands dirty.

Comment: @tarrsalah, first you hand the solution on a silver plate ([her previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15787541/577513)) and now you ask her to get "dirty"...

Comment: @Jesper.Reenberg my first answer was some kind of "welcome to SO !!".

Comment: Ok guys, you're right I'm apologizing, thanks to Tarrsalah and Jesper for their amazing welcome gift. I write my code but promise me help me to complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as per your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15787541/577513), you have a function `what_month`, which will return the month number of a given day of the year.

You could pretty simple iterate from `day_one` through `day_two`, calling your `what_month` function each time.

Now putting it all in a resulting list, could be done by concatenating the result of `what_month` with a recursive call to your function with the index incremented by one, concatenating with the empty list when your index reach `day_two`.